# Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007/2010: Unable to load the view. The View may have been modified to contain unsupported HTML such as iframes

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-infopath

I am trying to create a new blank form in InfoPath and i get the error

"InfoPath cannot load the view. The view may have been modified to contain unsupported HTML such as frames."

I am running windows XP, with IE7. No idea why im getting this error as this is the first time opening Office 2010.

I'm thinking the default templates got corrupted somehow.. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default view go corrupted and i had to start fresh..